# UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill of UIimageview working proper in iphone 4, but not in iphone4s

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, scrollview

I have written one code for scaling `UIImageview`. My problem is imageview is scaling correctly in iphone 4 , but not in iphone4s.

My code is below:

```
UIImageView *imgBG1 = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
[imgBG1 setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:nil];
        imgBG1.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imgBG1.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
                                      UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
[scrlView addSubview:imgBG1];
```

Note that i am capturing image from camera and assigning that image to imgBG1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try with different autoResizing properties. It should work. Whats the OS version?

Answer (score 0):

```
[imgBG1 setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

Also make sure the superview has set autoresizesSubviews to YES.

tell me its working or not :)